# Apache poi, cells missing when loading

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have a workbook where cell A1 is not appearing in the worksheet.  What could be the reason the first cell does not appear in the row cell collection.

[image: Cell values in the collection]

The spreadsheet

[image: Row 1 of the spreasdsheet]

Note there are 5 columns before the cell with 58-1 in it,  worksheet structure only has 3 cells.
What could be causing poi to apparently 'skip' 2 cells.

Comment: Are you trying to read an existing XLSX file? Can you show us the relevant code? (Please add it to the question as formatted text - thanks).

Comment: Your screenshot of the `_cells` `TreeMap` does not fit to the screenshot of the sheet. The screenshot of the sheet does not show the same row in sheet as the `_cells` `TreeMap`. According to the `_cells` `TreeMap` the cells in column `A` and `B` of the row are totally empty and so not present in sheet's storage. `Cell` iterators of that row will not contain that cells and `Cell cell = row.getCell(0);` will get `null` in `cell`, `cell = row.getCell(1);` will get `null` as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@AxelRichter I think you are on to something.  That made me look at the spreadsheet once more.  I found a number of Hidden Sheets with a names strikingly similar to what I 'thought' I was processing.  Additionally, my limited understanding how poi handles merged cells kinda mis-directed me.  User error.